# Find and replace strings in file using regex in sed. Script doesn't work

Tags: unix, sed, grep

I have a file, in which I have to find and change strings by specific pattern (phone number). The regex is:

```
^\+[0-9]{3} \([0-9]{2}\) [0-9]{7}$
```

When I use it in command:

```
grep "^\+[0-9]{3} \([0-9]{2}\) [0-9]{7}$" -E filename
```

It works. But when I try to use it in sed to replace all parenthesis by spaces and add spaces in 13 and 15 position, it doesn't works and I don't have ideas why.

My variants are:

```
sed '/^\+[0-9]{3} \([0-9]{2}\) [0-9]{7}$/s/[()]//' filename
```

(only for replacing parenthesis)

```
sed -e '/^\+[0-9]{3} \([0-9]{2}\) [0-9]{7}$/s/[()]//' -e '/^+[0-9]{2} ([0-9]{2}) [0-9]{7}/s/./& /11;s/./& /14' filename
```

file structure:

```
    +380 44 123 45 67
    +380 (44) 1234567
    +350 (56) 1454557
    +330 (76) 1255557
    +380 44 3534 45 67
    +320 (45) 1237887
    +310 (54) 1939997
    adasd
    asdddddddddddd
    sssdad
```

expected output:

```
    +380 44 123 45 67
    +380 44 123 45 67
    +350 56 145 45 57
    +330 76 125 55 57
    +380 44 3534 45 67
    +320 45 123 78 87
    +310 54 193 99 97
    adasd
    asdddddddddddd
    sssdad
```

Comment: you need to add `-E` option to `sed` command as well, which you use with `grep` for same purpose of using extended regex

Comment: @Sundeep thanks for response! but when I write: sed '/^\+[0-9]{3} \([0-9]{2}\) [0-9]{7}$/s/[()]//' -E filename it removes only opening parenthesis and I couldn't fix it(

Comment: well I didn't see if there were issues with regex as well.. would be good if you can add sample input file with expected output so that it can be tested... see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more details

Comment: @Sundeep
I've added it! I need to find and replace numbers in format +380 (44) 1234567 to format +380 44 123 45 67

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
$ cat ip.txt 
+380 44 123 45 67
+380 (44) 1234567
+350 (56) 1454557
+330 (76) 1255557
+380 44 3534 45 67
+320 (45) 1237887
+310 (54) 1939997
adasd
asdddddddddddd
sssdad

$ sed -E 's/^(\+[0-9]{3}) \(([0-9]{2})\) ([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})$/\1 \2 \3 \4 \5/' ip.txt 
+380 44 123 45 67
+380 44 123 45 67
+350 56 145 45 57
+330 76 125 55 57
+380 44 3534 45 67
+320 45 123 78 87
+310 54 193 99 97
adasd
asdddddddddddd
sssdad
```

- `()` can be used to surround a pattern so that the matched text inside them can be backreferenced in replacement section
- `\1` corresponds to first such captured group, `\2` to second and so on
- To match `(` or `)` themselves, we need to use escape them like `\(` and `\)`
- So, here the numbers are captured as per required output, excluding the `()` present in input line so that they are not part of output

Comment: Thanks! I don't have any idea how,but it works perfectly!

Comment: @andrew_j glad to know it works, I will add an explanation and let you know :)

Comment: Thank you very much, I've got it!

Answer (score 0):

Your sed command is wrong.
My way:

```
sed -E 's/^\+[0-9]{3} \([0-9]{2}\) [0-9]{7}$/[()]/'
```

Comment: I have trouble, `-E` of couse.

Comment: output doens't meet requirements that I've mentioned in question(

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sed -e 's|[()]||g' so-tel.txt | sed -E 's|([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})|\1 \2 \3|'
```

to transform `so-tel.txt`:

```
+380 44 123 45 67
+380 (44) 1234567
+350 (56) 1454557
+330 (76) 1255557
+380 44 3534 45 67
+320 (45) 1237887
+310 (54) 1939997
adasd
asdddddddddddd
sssdad
```

into:

```
+380 44 123 45 67
+380 44 123 45 67
+350 56 145 45 57
+330 76 125 55 57
+380 44 3534 45 67
+320 45 123 78 87
+310 54 193 99 97
adasd
asdddddddddddd
sssdad
```

**Explanation:**

```
's|[()]||g'
```

substitute any `(` and `)` with nothing, globally

```
's|([0-9]{3})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})|\1 \2 \3|'
```

substitute and capture seven successive digits in lengths 3, 2, and 2, with the captured digit groups separated by a space.

Comment: thanks, but problem is that I also need to add spaces in some positions only in strings which fit by regex

Comment: Yes, That's what I neeed!

Comment: You can see expected output in question